# Toggle by index or id react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am pulling categories and sub categories from an API which is working as expected. I have them in an accordion using expanded:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  ...
  expanded : false,
 }
}
```

Then rendering categories and sub categories:

```
renderFilter=()=> {
const items = [];
for (let item of this.state.docCats) {

  if( item.subCats) {
    docItems = item.subCats.map(row => {
      return<TouchableOpacity key={row.doc_sc_id} onPress={()=>this.FilterRequest(item.doc_cat_id, row.doc_sc_id)}><Text style={styles.filterCat}>{row.doc_sc_title}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    })
  }  

  items.push(
    <View key={item.doc_cat_id}>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.FilterRequest(item.doc_cat_id, '')}>
        <Text style={styles.filterCat}>{item.doc_cat_title}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.toggleExpand()}>
        <FontAwesome name={this.state.expanded ? 'chevron-up' : 'chevron-down'} size={20} color="#000"  />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {this.state.expanded &&
        docItems
      }
    </View>
  );

}

return items;
}
```

using a Toggle:

```
toggleExpand=()=>{
  this.setState({expanded : !this.state.expanded})
}
```

My problem is when i use the `toggleExpand` it expands all the accordions at the same time. Is there a way i can open them individually by targetting the index or id?

I would prefer not to use a different class/component as i need access to the other functions and fetch requests that i have.

Comment: use an array for toggled states

Comment: Just so I understand, `this.state.expanded` is used for all accordions or just one?

Comment: @goto1 `this.state.expanded` is used for all them - they all open at the same time when `onPress={()=>this.toggleExpand()}` is used rather than individually. I was hoping to use an index or the `item.doc_cat_id` to target them but i've not had much joy

Comment: @xadm - as in add `expanded : false` into my `this.state.docCats` array for each parent category? Not sure how that would work?

Comment: @S.B check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a property to each `docCats` item that indicates whether its accordion should be expanded or not, then pass an `id` to the `toggleExpand` function to update this property for a specific item and the `docCats` array that's stored in your `state`. Use the `expanded` property of each item inside of the `renderFilter` function to indicate whether the accordion should be expanded or not.

Here's a simplified example, but should give you a good idea how to rewrite your code to make it work:

```js
const items = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, idx) => ({
  id: idx,
  title: `Accordion ${idx + 1}`
}));

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: items.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        expanded: false
      }))
    };
  }

  toggleExpand = id => {
    const nextItems = [...this.state.items].map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          expanded: !item.expanded
        };
      }
      return item;
    });
    this.setState({
      items: nextItems
    });
  };

  renderFilter = () => {
    return this.state.items.map(item => (
      <div
        style={{ border: `1px solid black`, width: `100`, height: `100` }}
        onClick={() => this.toggleExpand(item.id)}
        key={item.id}
      >
        <p>
          {item.title} {item.expanded ? `is expanded` : `is not expanded`}
        </p>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    const renderedFilter = this.renderFilter();

    return <div>{renderedFilter}</div>;
  }
}
```

If you'd like to see it in action, simply click on each box to change the `expanded` state, here's the link to a working demo:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-keller-dgm70?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Just looked at this just now and got it to work with my code. Thanks :)

Comment: @S.B glad I was able to help